# Debian: Move the trash folder for all users to another volume

Tags: debian, trash

I need to have all deleted files for all users go into a folder on another drive. Is this possible? If so, what are the commands to permanently move the trash folder(s)?

The operating system is Debian Jessie.

Thanks.

Comment: At home I do not move the kitchen trash into the living room, so I can empty the kitchen trash. And at work the cleaners empty my trash bin and dispose of the trash nightly. The same policy should be implemented on your cloud server.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the way your system is set up. If whenever a file is deleted, it moves it into a trash directory (e.g `~/Trash/`) then you can run `sudo mv /home/*/Trash/* path-to-drive` . 
If instead you want to move every file a user deletes into a drive, then you could make a simple script in your `/bin` directory that goes as follows:
`#!/bin/bash`
`sudo mv $1 path-to-drive`
And then name it `del`. You would just have to add `alias rm="del"` to your `/etc/bash.bashrc`...
Cheers,
*Interesting...*

Comment: This is an ownCloud server. When users delete files they go to the Trash just in case they need restored. We need the server to use a MUCH larger drive or it fills up the system drive within a couple of days. So, basically, we need any files deleted to go to a Trash folder on a different volume. I don't know if this is possible.... but I hope it is.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create a soft link with ln?

Rather than copy from another answer here's the link.
[Stackoverflow: how to create a link to a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587445/how-to-create-a-link-to-a-directory)